# How to derive corrected sum of squares and the corrected sum of cross products given LHS of the equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

I am self-studying the book *INTRODUCTION TO LINEAR REGRESSION ANALYSIS by Montgomery et al.*, where it is not clear to me how to reach the RHS of the equations (2.9) & (2.10) from the given LHS.
I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Equation (2.9) is as follows:
$$S_{xx}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2} - \frac{\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} \right )^{2}}{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i} -\overline{x})^2$$

and Equation (2.10) is as follows:
$$S_{xy}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}x_{i}- \frac{\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i} \right )\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} \right )}{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i(x_{i} -\overline{x})$$

where, $$\overline{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, thanks. done editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the proofs are as follows,

For eqn. (2.9)
\begin{align*} 
&S_{xx}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2} - \frac{\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} \right )^{2}}{n} =\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i} -\overline{x})^{2} \\
&where,  \overline{x}= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x}_i \\ \\
&RHS = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i} -\overline{x})^{2} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}^2 - 2x_{i}\overline{x} + \overline{x}^2)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{n}2x_{i}\overline{x} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\overline{x}^2  \\
&\text{Since, } \overline{x}\text{ is a constant,} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \overline{x}^2=
\overline{x}^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}1=n\overline{x}^2 \\ 
&RHS = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2 - 2\overline{x}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} + n\overline{x}^2  \\
&RHS = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2 - 2n\overline{x}^2 + n\overline{x}^2  \\
&RHS = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2 - n\overline{x}^2   \\
&RHS = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2 - n(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}{n})^2   \\
&RHS = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2 - \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i})^2}{n} = LHS   \\
\end{align*}
####################################################################

and for Eqn (2.10)
\begin{align*} 
&S_{xy}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}x_{i} - \frac{\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i} \right )\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} \right )}{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}(x_{i} -\overline{x}) \\
&where,  \overline{x}= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x}_i \\ \\
&RHS =\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}(x_{i} -\overline{x}) \\ \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}x_{i}-y_{i}\overline{x})\\ \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}x_{i})-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}\overline{x})\\ \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}x_{i})-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x}_i) \\ \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}x_{i})-\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x}_i)\\ \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}x_{i}-\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i})(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x}_i)}{n}\\ \\
&= LHS
\end{align*}